# How to parse a file with special delimiters in a batch file?

Tags: file, parsing, batch-file, delimiter

I want to parse a file that looks like this using batch :

```
a: string_containing_various_characters,.:and spaces/1
b: string_containing_various_characters,.:and spaces/2
c: string_containing_various_characters,.:and spaces/3
d: string_containing_various_characters,.:and spaces/4
e: string_containing_various_characters,.:and spaces/5
f: string_containing_various_characters,.:and spaces/6
g: string_containing_various_characters,.:and spaces/7
```

I need to extract every string following "a: ","b: ","c: " etc... I can't use space as a delimiter since there can be spaces in the strings. The only thing that is always true is that the first ": " will always be where I want to cut the line.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in (file) do for /f "delims=:" %%c in ("%%~b") do echo %%c
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. Care to explain why? I realize I'm having a hard time dealing with colons. My next step is to create variables containing the strings, with the names being the part of the line before the colon, like this : a="string_containing_various_characters,.:and spaces/1". I Had the idea to delete the last character of %%a with the syntax %variable:StrToFind=NewStr%, but since StrToFind is ":", it creates a double colon. Any ideas?

Comment: No need for 2 FOR loops. `for /f "tokens=1* delims=: " %%a in (file) do set "%%a=%%b"`

Comment: @Endoro, thanks for the update. However, this is correct if I want a=string : `for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in (Request_Header.txt) do for /f "delims=:" %%c in ("%%~a") do set %%c=%%b`.